# How to add column to a series of text files in Python as you read into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have 8 different .txt files, all in the same format and I'd like to add a column to each to essentially label that set of data before merging all 8 .txt files into a Pandas dataframe.

**Input: text file 1 (files 2-8 have same format)**

```
585978391360221184|Thu Apr 09 01:31:50 +0000 2015|Recipes for Summer http://bbc.in/1CimpJF 
583616089340280832|Thu Apr 02 13:04:53 +0000 2015|Health highlights http://bbc.in/1EKlFCK
```

**Desired output (with labels added at end)**

```
585978391360221184|Thu Apr 09 01:31:50 +0000 2015|Recipes for Summer http://.in/1CimpJF|BBC
583616089340280832|Thu Apr 02 13:04:53 +0000 2015|Health highlights http://bbc.in/1EKlFCK|BBC
```

Once I have all those labels added to each text file, I believe I could simply merge the 8 files and read them into a Pandas DataFrame. What's the best way to add those labels to the data to do this easily in Python? Is there a way I can do it automatically on all 8 files without doing it manually on each one?

Comment: This is likely too broad, please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: if by `merge` you mean [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to just create a DataFrame with more rows then you can use the `keys` argument, which will add a label as a MultIndex label, essentially allowing you to label all rows from a single file. I.e. something like `pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1', 'df2'])`, which is shown explicitly in the documentation examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
files = ['d.csv','d1.csv']       # List of files
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='|', header=None)         # read file
    df['label']='BBC'                                    # add new column
    df.to_csv(file, header=None, sep='|', index=None)    # store file
```

IIUC you want to write 'BBC' label in each files.